# Create a table from survey results

Tags: r

I have the following data and I was wondering how to generate a table of the frequency from each response via base, plyr, or another package.

My data:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                Did_you_use_tv=c("tv","","","tv","tv"),
                Did_you_use_internet=c("","","","int","int"))
df
```

I can run a table and get the frequencies for any column using the table

```
table(df[,2])
table(df[,2], df[,3])
```

However, how can I go about setting up the data so it looks like below.

```
df2 = data.frame(Did_you_use_tv=c(3), 
                Did_you_use_internet=c(2))
df2
```

It's just a summary of frequencies for each column.

I'm going to be creating cross tabs but given the structure of the data, I feel this may be a little more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar in concept to @Tyler's answer. Just take the sum of all values that are not equal to `""`:

```
colSums(!df[-1] == "")
#       Did_you_use_tv Did_you_use_internet 
#                    3                    2
```

---

#### Update

Fellow Stack Overflow user [@juba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249691/juba) has done some work [on a function called `multi.table`](https://github.com/juba/questionr/blob/master/R/table.multi.r#L35) which looks like this:

```
multi.table <- function(df, true.codes=NULL, weights=NULL) {
  true.codes <- c(as.list(true.codes), TRUE, 1)
  as.table(sapply(df, function(v) {
    sel <- as.numeric(v %in% true.codes)
    if (!is.null(weights)) sel <- sel * weights
    sum(sel)
  }))
}
```

The function is part of the [**questionr** package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/questionr/index.html).

Usage in your example would be:

```
library(questionr)
multi.table(df[-1], true.codes=list("tv", "int"))
#       Did_you_use_tv Did_you_use_internet 
#                    3                    2
```

Comment: Similar?  This is way better. +1

Comment: The virtual +1 is tangible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach of many that came to mind:

```
FUN <- function(x) sum(x != "")
do.call(cbind, lapply(df[, -1], FUN))

##     Did_you_use_tv Did_you_use_internet
## [1,]              3                    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach

```
> do.call(cbind, lapply(df[,-1], table))[-1, ]
      Did_you_use_tv Did_you_use_internet 
                   3                    2
```

Answer (score 0):

With `plyr` and `reshape2`

```
t(dcast(subset(melt(df,id.var="id"), value!=""), variable ~ .))
```